# How to let rails only check current database's migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-migrations

I use rails 4 , and has to migrate folder under db/migrate,for example:
db/migrate/A , db/migrate/B .

I have success used A migration file create A database schema , used B migration file create B database schema .

But when i connect A database , and start my rails server , it check all my migration file under db/migrate..,and show the message :

"Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development"

Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to run proposed command?

Comment: Are you connecting to the correct database in config/database.yml? 

You cant have 2 separate migrations running on the same database... they will just toggle each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue, run:

```
bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
```

That will apply the migrations that are pending.